# Get difference between Two Struct Slices/Array based on certain fields (Golang)

Tags: arrays, go, struct, slice

I am new to Golang and currently having some difficulty retrieving the difference value of 2 struct slices.

I have 2 slices of structs data and I want to get the difference of the first 3 struct fields between them. So if AppointmentType, Date and Time does not match it will return the value.

The user field can be ignored..

I have tried using the solution here but I am unable to configure it to match my struct.. Please do assist on this..! Thank you!

[How to find the difference between two slices of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374219/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-slices-of-strings)

```
type AppointmentsDetail struct {
    AppointmentType string 
    Date            string 
    Time            string 
    User            string
}

Slice 1: [{Consult 01-12-2022 15:00 Nil} {Surgery 02-12-2022 12:00 Nil} {Surgery 01-01-2022 12:00 Nil} {Surgery 11-11-2023 12:00 Nil}]

Slice 2: [{Consult 01-12-2022 15:00 Admin} {Surgery 02-12-2022 12:00 Admin}]
```

```
getDifference(slice1, slice2)
Output: [{Surgery 01-01-2022 12:00 Admin} {Surgery 11-11-2023 12:00 Admin}]
```

Comment: You can concat struct fields as a string and compare them to get different.

Comment: Use the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428032/5728991) with type `string` replaced by `AppointmentsDetail`.

Comment: What problem did you run into trying to implement the linked question/answers?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Hello sorry, I updated my question.. I am trying to get the differences of the first 3 fields of the structs that matches instead of the entire data..

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I just updated my question sorry for the confusion..

Comment: Using [ANisus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374861/11424673) should work if you change the equality check `if s1 == s2` to something you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use embedded struct. Hope this helps.

```
type AppointmentsDetail struct {
    Data
    User string
}

type Data struct{ AppointmentType, Date, Time string }

func main() {
    var p1 = []AppointmentsDetail{
        {Data{"Consult", "01-12-2022", "15:00"}, "Nil"}, {Data{"Surgery", "02-12-2022", "12:00"}, "Nil"},
        {Data{"Surgery", "01-01-2022", "12:00"}, "Nil"}, {Data{"Surgery", "11-11-2023", "12:00"}, "Nil"},
    }
    var p2 = []AppointmentsDetail{
        {Data{"Consult", "01-12-2022", "15:00"}, "Admin"},
        {Data{"Surgery", "02-12-2022", "12:00"}, "Admin"},
    }

    fmt.Println(getDifference(p1, p2))
}

func getDifference(a, b []AppointmentsDetail) []AppointmentsDetail {
    mb := make(map[Data]struct{}, len(b))

    for _, x := range b {
        mb[x.Data] = struct{}{}
    }

    var diff []AppointmentsDetail
    for _, x := range a {

        if _, found := mb[x.Data]; !found {
            diff = append(diff, x)
        }
    }
    return diff
}
```

Output:
`[{{Surgery 01-01-2022 12:00} Nil} {{Surgery 11-11-2023 12:00} Nil}]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works too for an embedded struct but I needed to work with my given struct itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hello all I got the solution based on the suggestions [How to find the difference between two slices of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374219/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-slices-of-strings)

I modified the code and tweak it a little to my needs. Thank you all for your help!

```
func getAvailableAppointments() []AppointmentsDetail {
    
// Slices can be placed in any other (as it will be swapped eventually)
    allAppt := getAppointments()
    bookedAppt := getBookedAppointmentsData()

    var diff []AppointmentsDetail

    //Loop twice to swap
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        for _, s1 := range bookedAppt {
            found := false
            for _, s2 := range allAppt {
                if s1.Date == s2.Date && s1.Time == s2.Time && s1.AppointmentType == s2.AppointmentType {
                    fmt.Println("Match", s2)
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if !found {
                diff = append(diff, s1)
            }
        }
        // Swap the slices, only if it was the first loop
        if i == 0 {
            bookedAppt, allAppt = allAppt, bookedAppt
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Difference:", diff)
    return diff
}
```